# Effect with javascript does not support separete lines

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this codes that are cycling through the alpha variables and then stop at the intended characters.

```js
const alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ', '.', ',', '\''];
var progress = 0;
var output = ''
const chalk = require('chalk');
const fs = require('fs');
var text = fs.readFileSync("text.txt").toString()


function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
        currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date <
        milliseconds);
}
function effect() {
    console.time("Time Anticipated ")
    while (text != output) {
        var randomNums = Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)
        if (alpha[randomNums] == text[progress]) {
            output += text[progress]
            console.log(chalk.red(output))
            progress++
            sleep(20)
        } else {
            console.log(chalk.red(`${output}${alpha[randomNums]}`))
            sleep(1.2)
        }
        console.clear()
    }

    console.log(chalk.green(output))
    console.timeEnd("Time Anticipated ")
}
effect()
```

There's also a text file which is being read to the text variable:

> This a test text if this file has been read by JavaScript.
> Now this a test if this file has been successfully console.log.

The 2nd text of line was not being read properly and thus the code was stuck in a continues loop.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Where do you ever change the value of `text` such that your `while (text != output)` would turn false?

Comment: i don't get it @Marc

Comment: You say your problem is an infinite loop, right? Why would you expect your `while` loop in the `effect()` function to terminate?

Comment: i'm not terminating the function i just want it to be able to read the second line of the text which is not doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the newline characters to your list `\r` `\n`.

```
const alpha = [ ..., '\r', '\n'];
```

As a side note, [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) will give you a non busy wait.